# Is AWS Lambda possible without webpack now

Tags: webpack, aws-lambda

I used webpack when I was building serverless functions for AWS Lambda.  Now that the newest version supports 8.10 I was wondering if webpack is required at all?  the advantage I see is that on the console itself I can now debug the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can build functions by hand and just upload them via the command line or, if you really want, in the gui backend.

If you like the features of Webpack then use it, but it's certainly not required.

Comment: thanks for this, however my function is using a number of shared utilities and other functions.  How do I upload a whole bunch?